# Vaadin RichTextArea content to PDF through FOP

Tags: pdf, vaadin, apache-fop, richtextarea

We need to transform content of RichTextArea to pdf with all formatting, alignment, images etc. Is any simple way to do it? Or we have to write some kind of parser? We are using fop to transform xml to pdf.

Thanks. Best regards

dEVIANT

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use external libraries such as `iText`. But, you have to build by yourself the pdf you want to send back to the client.

So, IMHO, with this method, there is no way to push your textarea content as typed and have it converted into a pdf file without a manual formatting.

Regards.